# binary classifying model in pytorch using cnn

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, conv-neural-network, convolution

i build a classifying model about phishing site.

**1. first, about my data**

> num_dataset: i have about 16000 dataset

> num_feature: my dataset has 12 characterisitics.

> label: if it's a phishing site, i set it's label -1. else 1

> batch_size: set batch_size 128, for cnn model

> kernel_size: 3

**2. I try**

```
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, TensorDataset

train_dataset = TensorDataset(x_train, y_train)
train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)

#-------------------------------------------------------#
class CNN(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, kernel_size):
    super().__init__()  
    self.layer1 = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv1d(12, 32, 3,
                  stride=1, padding=1)
...

  def forward(self, x):
    out = self.layer1(x)
...
#-------------------------------------------------------#
model = CNN()

for epoch in range(epochs):
  avg_cost = 0

  for x_train, y_train in train_loader:

    Hypothesis = model(x_train)
```

x_train.shape

> torch.Size([16072, 12])

y_train.shape

> torch.Size([16072, 1])

**3. Error**

at `Hypothesis = model(x_train)`

RuntimeError: Expected 3-dimensional input for 3-dimensional weight [32, 12, 3], but got 2-dimensional input of size [128, 12] instead

**4. Finnally**

i think it's because I'm confused between conv1d and conv2d  but i can't figure it out...

plz, i want to know the cause of this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a [`nn.Conv1d`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Conv1d.html) which should receive a 3-dimensional input shaped `(batch_size, n_channels, sequence_length)`. This being said your input has `n_channels=12` (since you've initialized your 1d conv with 12 input channels) and a `sequence_length=1`. To match the requirements, you need to have an additional dimension on your input. Passing something like `x_train.unsqueeze(-1)` to your network should work.

See the following example:

```
>>> x = torch.rand(100, 12, 1)
>>> L = nn.Conv1d(12, 32, 3, stride=1, padding=1)
>>> L(x).shape
torch.Size([100, 32, 1])
```

Comment: Thank you so very very very much. it worked out! I wish i could help someone else like you soon!!!!!

Comment: have you a nice day, and hope you had a great day